# How can I describe jobs in Azkaban UI?

Tags: azkaban

I just discovered Azkaban and I want to know if it is possible to put some description next to the jobs/flows in the project view ?

(See [this image](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/47/5/1511511242-capture.png) for more accuracy)

Comment: What about simply using more descriptive names for your steps?

Comment: This one is just a sample I got from [Github](https://github.com/joeharris76/azkaban_examples), sure we can be more verbose on the names but some jobs will be a bit more complex and I'm afraid than just a "better name" won't be enough to describe what it exactly does. Moreover, those same jobs will be used by some other people that won't necessarily have written the jobs themselves